# Cloned laravel project Dropzone storage link

Tags: php, laravel

I have set **Laravel dropzone** and it's working on my project.

I have cloned that project and trying to modify things but when I'm trying to upload files it's working and they are in the storage but when I want to see my files that I have uploaded I get

```
404
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. error
```

This is my [link](http://mylocal.test/storage/storage/eOSuhkeabtKGuj4PRGePv0dxl8Fl0iQ3n7qLKvHs.pdf)  when I click on the document

I'm using **Laragon**

EDIT:

I noticed that I have public >storage>storage
path:
public\storage\storage
And also a file named storage where I have a public file with an app file where inside  I have another storage file 
something like

```
path:
storage\app\public\storage\
```

Comment: You have posted a link where the authority (host) is `mylocal.test`, We for sure couldn't reach that link ;-]. Anyway I see it a double storage path `storage/storage/` is that right?

Comment: same error with your **link** as well

Comment: @shadowsheep   this link isn't the real one im working on local and using Laragon so ofcourse you can't see it but it's a double storage yes and it's working with the original project without problem I don't know why it's not working on my clone project :)

Comment: No i don't hink so @H45H the same link Storage/storage... is working on my original project

Comment: thanks guys i found the solution

Comment: Hi! Glad you solved your problem. The convention on this site is to always keep questions and answers separate, so rather than editing the question to say "solved", you should add your own Answer below, and then "Accept" it with the tick-mark button.

Comment: You got it! Glad to know ^_^

Comment: okty I will do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: when you clone your project delete public>storage and run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

to link it with your new path

Answer (score 0):

Your link is looks like incorrect, `http://mylocal.test/storage/storage/eOSuhkeabtKGuj4PRGePv0dxl8Fl0iQ3n7qLKvHs.pdf` the storage path repeated on the url.

Can you try single `storage` path in the url?

`http://mylocal.test/storage/eOSuhkeabtKGuj4PRGePv0dxl8Fl0iQ3n7qLKvHs.pdf`

Comment: Is there ``storage`` folder in your public folder? You can't access directly ``storage`` folder in your project root. But you can symlink it to public folder via ``php artisan storage:link`` command. If you didn't run it command, you can't access the file.

Comment: I run it they are saying their is already a public/storage  directory that exists

Comment: yes I have storage file in my public file but it's empty even if I download the files in dropzone they are registred in the storage >app >public>storage but not  in public>storage

Comment: It's nice news.

Comment: I edited the post for newbies like me to solve it next time :]

Comment: I do not understand, who give 'down vote' my answer? And Why? Someone always give me 'down vote' but he/she never do an explain :)

Comment: It's not me brother btw I did  an up vote right now so maybe it's not down anymore but it's not counted